# Type hints of function with object child arguments does not accept child classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, python-3.7, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement a type-hinted event subscription mechanism.

The listener subscribes by passing a handler function.
The subscribe function accepts any method that can handle BaseEvents.

However, when I narrow down the childclass, I get a type warning.

```py
from typing import Callable


class BaseEvent:
  pass

class ChildEvent(BaseEvent):
  pass


class Listener:
  def __init__(self):
    # Expected type '(BaseEvent) -> None', got '(event: ChildEvent) -> None' instead 
    self.subscribe(handler=self.handler)

    pass

  def subscribe(self, handler: Callable[[BaseEvent], None]):
    pass

  def handler(self, event: ChildEvent):
    pass
```

I understand that the 'contract' requires the handler to accept *any* BaseEvent, and that this approach does not satisfy Liskov substitution, but since Python has no interfaces, how can I "enforce" that the handler is going to at least handle some classes extending BaseEvent, and not strings for example?

Comment: Well, your handler needs to accept a `BaseEvent`, not a `ChildEvent`. `subscribe` defines that it may/will pass a `BaseEvent` to `handler`, which would be a type error here (since `ChildEvent` may implement methods/attributes that `BaseEvent` doesn't which'll lead to an error, hence the warning is correct).

Comment: This is an example of [contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).  Maybe you can add a generic type to your `Listener` class to specify which event each listener can handle.